# Azure MySQL Workbench 8.0.25 DDLs messed up

Tags: mysql, azure, ddl, workbench

I am running an Azure MySql Database.

I updated mysql Workbench, and now the DDLs for my views are only one line and unbeautifieable.

The DDLs of older views can no longer be parsed, are not nicely put in backticks as they used to were put.

Downgrading to .23 did not help.

Thanks for a quick help.

Answer (score 0):

It was the version of Workbench.
It has to be the same as the one you get from the query:

```
select version();
```

I had to downgrade to .15.
Found it in the current known issues section here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-limits